# Exclusive disjunction and intersection of two sets not partition of the union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A, B$ are sets
$P = \{A\cap B , A \oplus B\}$, why can't I say $P$ is a partition of $A \cup B$?

Am I missing some corner case?
For example for these two sets, I can't understand why it's not a partition:
$A = \{1,2,3,4\},B= \{3,4,5,6\}$

Comment: The members of a partition are required to be non-empty.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, can you give me an example of where it's empty?

Comment: Take $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint sets. Or the same set. Or let one of them be empty. $A\cap B$ and $A\oplus B$ are a partition of $A\cup B$ iff $A\ne\varnothing\ne B$, $A\ne B$, and $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$.